# Subquery do SQL Server está sempre retornando nulo. Como consertar.

Tags: sql, query, sql-server-2012, null

Eu tenho uma procedure e uma COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION(subquery). 
Essa minha CTE faz uma busca e oferece para a minha query o resultado, a minha query então utiliza os resultados da mesma.

Na minha tabela Endereço eu possuo um campo "Complemento" que permite valores nulos.
No entanto quando a minha CTE faz a consulta e compara com o @complemento se o complemento tiver vazio, o resultado da CTE não retorna nada, mesmo o valor NULL existindo na tabela_endereco, já o contrário, se for procurar um registro cujo complemento está preenchido a pesquisa encontra.

Vou mostrar para vocês o código e o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação 1: O erro acontece pois a FK não aceita valores nulos e como a subquery retorna valor nulo, esse erro acontece. 
Observação 2: A outra procedure após o EXEC faz apenas cadastro de endereços.

Answer (score 1):

Quando a coluna complemento da tabela, tem o valor NULL numa linha, para que esta seja devolvida pela query não basta fazer:

```
[...] where complemento = @complemento [...]
```

Os valores NULL não podem ser comparados com o operador =.

Para que as linhas a NULL sejam devolvidas,  pode ser feito assim:

```
[...] where complemento = @complemento or (complemento is null and @complemento is null) [...]
```

Ou então assim:

```
[...] where isnull(complemento,'') = isnull(@complemento,'') [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IDENTITY_SCOPE` pra pegar a chave primária do último registro inserido e adicionar na outra tabela. Dependendo de como suas tabelas foram criadas, se você colocou restrição de chave estrangeira, use cascateamneto para fazer o CRUD completo.

Answer (score 0):

O erro apresentado no *print*, é porque a consulta "(SELECT ID_Endereco FROM CTE_ENDERECO)" não trouxe nenhum resultado ou seja NULL e você tentou atribuir este resultado ao campo "FK_Endereco" da tabela "Tabela_Representante" (que não permite nulo).

O erro do *print* poderia ser resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```
DECLARE @FK_Endereco AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @FK_Endereco = (SELECT ID_Endereco FROM CTE_ENDERECO);
```

Troque na sua consulta, na linha do insert:

O valor:

```
(SELECT ID_Endereco FROM CTE_ENDERECO)
```

Pelo valor:

```
(CASE WHEN @FK_Endereco IS NULL OR @FK_Endereco = '' THEN 'Sem Endereço' ELSE @FK_Endereco END)
```

Não entendi a relação do erro citado com a comparação do valor da coluna "complemento" com a variável "@complemento". Esta comparação que você disse não aparece nos *prints* de tela.

Se o problema for ao dar o select no campo "complemento" da tabela "CTE_ENDERECO" basta usar:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN complemento IS NULL THEN '' ELSE complemento END) AS complemtento FROM CTE_ENDERECO
```

Ao invés de dar um simples SELECT no campo que pode ser nulo (como você deve estar fazendo):

```
SELECT complemento FROM CTE_ENDERECO
```